# Asp.net Radio button sequence rendering

Tags: asp.net

I have two radio buttons(asp.net) as `rb1` and `rb2` and `GroupName` is applied for both as `Grp` in my form. While Page is rendering, need to render first `rb2`  and lastly `rb1`.

**Are there any predefined properties for rendering sequence?**

Example:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" Text="Radio Button1" GroupName="Grp" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" Text="Radio Button2" GroupName="Grp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this type..

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" runat="server" GroupName="Grp" Text="Button1" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rtbn2" runat="server" GroupName="Grp" Text="Button2" />
```

Personally, I prefer to use a RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSystem" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="button1" Value="button1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="button2" Value="button2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Does this change the rendering sequence?

Comment: Yes,  @mbharanidharan